# updateOrCreate won't work on Lumen but working on tinker with DB::beginTrans()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, lumen

I want to ask, how to use updateOrCreate properly? Since I tried it using tinker, it works well, but the same code that's run via lumen controller, won't work. No even send any error or such, just stop on the code

See this Thinker

```
>>> DB::beginTransaction();

=> null

>>> MhProductUnit::updateOrCreate(["id_mh_product" => 1, "unit" => "KRT"], [

"order" => 2,

"unit" => "KRT",

"amount" => 1,

"created_by" => 1

]);

PHP Fatal error: Class 'MhProductUnit' not found in Psy Shell code on line 1

>>> \App\Models\MhProductUnit::updateOrCreate(["id_mh_product" => 1, "unit" => "KODI"], [

"order" => 2,

"unit" => "KODI",

"amount" => 3,

"created_by" => 1

]);

=> App\Models\MhProductUnit {#716

id_mh_product: 1,

unit: "KODI",

order: 2,

amount: 3,

id: 9,

}

>>> \App\Models\MhProductUnit::updateOrCreate(["id_mh_product" => 1, "unit" => "PSG"], [

"order" => 3,

"unit" => "PSG",

"amount" => 20,

"created_by" => 1

]);

=> App\Models\MhProductUnit {#745

id_mh_product: 1,

unit: "PSG",

order: 3,

amount: 20,

id: 11,

}

>>> DB::commit();

=> null

>>>
```

but on the same time, with code, it won't work

```
DB::beginTransaction();

foreach ($unit as $key => $u) {    
MhProductUnit::updateOrCreate(["id_mh_product" => $productID, "unit" => ""], [
"order" => $key,
"unit" => $u["unit"],
"amount" => $u["amount"],
"price" => 0, // Tidak ada harga di sini,
"created_by" => $userID
                        ]);
                    }

DB::commit();
```

it will stop on the first iteration (assume that all variable are filled, and working all the way), on Lumen 5.8.

Comment: For no reason, it just work. Oh God. I have no Idea.. I done nothing to the code

Comment: Use full namespaces `App\MhProductUnit`. Probably would work without leading backslash.

Comment: @Tpojka nope that's not the problem, because I already do the use App\Models\MhProductUnit.

Comment: Put that block in try catch. In catch part write log.

Comment: Uhm it's just working anyway. I still can't figure up why. Same code :'D

Comment: Have you set logging of `$e->getMessage()` in catch block? That should say why.

Comment: Nah no error on that part, it's just blank last time, but it's working now. So I think I should close this question :'D

Comment: Use as many as possible try/catch blocks, it will make your coding easier.